# efficient memory scheduler algorithm in real time systesm

Tags: linux, algorithm, memory

I am working on a project where an algorithm in real-time system that learns the memory access pattern and accordingly swap the pages from main memory to secondary memory. also finds the inter dependency between the accessed data and pre-fetch the data accordingly.

I would like to know, if any existing approach to solve this problem efficiently?

Comment: Look up `preload` project

Comment: Do you mean in a system where you have not got enough RAM to keep all your code/data in RAM at all times, and end up swapping, you want the swap-in process to load the code/data before it actually is being accessed? Seems pretty difficult to get right, to me.

Comment: Peter, yes, In my case, the flash memory (main memory) is limited, so based on the usage/learning, i have to predict and pre-fetch the data from secondary memory. hope this is clear enough. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try [Tiros](http://tiros.sourceforge.net/) or [real-time-scheduler project](http://sourceforge.net/projects/rtsched/).